# In Clojure, how would I redefine vars for a lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

In a namespace, I have two dynamic vars:

```
(def ^:dynamic *form-data*)
(def ^:dynamic *form-errors*)
```

In order to quickly create new bindings for them, I've made a wrapper macros:

```
(defmacro with-form [data errors & body]
  `(binding [*form-data*    ~data 
             *form-errors*  ~errors]
     ~@body))
```

I have several functions in the same namespace that rely on those vars, one of them is `input-field`.

It works when I use the function by itself, in a repl. But when I use it this way:

```
(vf/with-form {} {}
  (map #(vf/input-field hf/text-field %) [:name :code]))
```

I get an error: `Attempting to call unbound fn: *form-errors*`

I guess the problem is that `bindings` runs `map`, creates a lazy seq, and unbounds the vars back to their original state. Is there a way around this limitation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `doall` to force the entire lazy seq to be realised:

```clj
(vf/with-form {} {}
  (doall (map #(vf/input-field hf/text-field %) [:name :code])))
```

This [example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding#example-60746e7de4b0b1e3652d74c4) in the docs for `binding` illustrates the same technique.

Alternatively, to retain laziness use `bound-fn*`, as demonstrated by this [example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bound-fn*#example-602d86fde4b0b1e3652d7456) in the docs:

```clj
(vf/with-form {} {}
  (map (bound-fn* #(vf/input-field hf/text-field %)) [:name :code]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement the previous answer, please see this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

In particular, I alway like to use `mapv` instead of `map`. It is equivalent to

```
(vec (map ...))
```

and it avoids the "gotchas" created by lazy-sequences.